# MYSQL Transform Data

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, sorry for my bad English :)

I have following example table data:

id   name   state   amount
1   name1   open     2
1   name1   open     3
1   name1   closed   4
2   name2   open     5
2   name2   closed   8
2   name2   closed   4

I want to aggregate amount data for each state (open or closed) and name (name1 or name2)
something like this:

id   name   open(sum amount)   closed(sum amount)
1   name1          5(2+3)                              4
2   name2          5                              12(8+4)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN state="open" THEN amount else 0 END) AS `open`,
SUM(CASE WHEN state="closed" THEN amount else 0 END) AS `closed`
FROM <yourtablename>
GROUP BY id;
```

Mind the special quotes in the derived column names, they cannot be replaced by a different type of quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the already chosen answer another way of doing this is :

```
SELECT
     id
    ,name
    ,SUM( IF( state = 'open' ,amount ,0 ) ) open_total
    ,SUM( IF( state = 'closed' ,amount ,0 ) ) closed_total
FROM
    `data`
WHERE
    1
GROUP BY
    name
```